# Recording ants: mic recommendations?

Tags: field-recording, contact-mic, insects

I have been recording ants for some time now, using the simplest Korg clip-on mic. I am in search of three things:

1. A better contact mic that will pick up less environmental/ambient sound.
2. A contact mic that I can run underground into a nest or other substrate.
3. A super sensitive microphone (not a contact mic) that only picks up sound close to the mic (ha ha does this exist?)
4. A patron to support my work (heh heh)

What kind of mic would work here?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into condenser microphones? Instead of the dynamic mics, condensers are used for more intimate sound recordings. Additional, the Sanken brand makes some microphones for such needs. "Sanken [makes a mic] called the MO-64, which is capable of recording the heartbeat of a snail."

[enter link description here](http://www.sanken-mic.com/en/product/index.cfm#product1)

Comment: I have been unable to find the MO-64 mic in the provided link, although it is mentioned in this page : http://www.sanken-mic.com/en/company/product.cfm

Comment: Thank you for this info! I am in search of the MO-64, which is discontinued. I am hoping to be able to rent one from someone.

Answer (score 0):

Sanken CO-100k. This has become an "industry standard" for those of us who want to record at the highest frequencies (currently) possible, 100kHz. For sound designers like myself, this mic opens up a whole world of possibilities when the original sound is slowed down to just a fraction of it's normal speed. The key to using this mic is to pair it with a high quality recorder (Sound Devices) and the cleanest preamp you can get your hands on (my friend uses a Cooper which is insanely quiet).

http://www.sanken-mic.com/en/product/product.cfm/3.1000400

Comment: Thanks so much for this info!
I ended up purchasing a Dodotronics Ultramic 384K. We will see how that works for my studies. The CO-100K is beyond my budget for now. Sanken made a mic that I really wish I could get my hands on, the MO-64, but it is discontinued and also beyond my budget. I am looking around to see if I can borrow or rent one from someone. Fingers crossed! Do you work in the film industry? 

all the best, 
Lisa

Comment: I do work in the film industry. See my IMDb for credits. Also, pls upvote and star answers that you find helpful - it benefits the entire community.